# SQL - query returns duplicate records even with GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have this query:

```
SELECT P.*,
     ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('37.785834') ) 
     * cos( radians( CA.lat ) ) 
     * cos( radians( CA.lng ) 
     - radians('-122.406417') ) 
     + sin( radians('37.785834') ) 
     * sin( radians( CA.lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM adp2_posts as P 
JOIN adp2_offer_details C ON C.merchant_id = P.ID 
JOIN adp2_addresses CA ON CA.address_id = C.address_id 
WHERE P.post_type = 'merchant' 
    AND P.post_status = 'publish' 
    AND CA.mm = "dallasftworth" 
    AND C.cats RLIKE CONCAT("[[:<:]]", REPLACE(199, ",", "[[:>:]]|[[:<:]]"), "[[:>:]]") 
GROUP BY CA.address_id, P.ID 
HAVING (distance < 999999999999999999 AND P.coupon_count > 0) ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 0 , 20
```

I expect it to return unique values from LEFT table, but it returns duplicates too.

Results:

[image: the results]

I am a bit confused by this one.

Comment: If you group by A,B you get a row per unique combination of A,B

Comment: You have `SELECT P.*` in your query, suggesting there are more columns than the one in the image. That could easily indicate a misuse/misunderstanding of `GROUP BY` in MySQL.  Please post a more complete result set from your query, and a sample of how you _expect_ or _intend_ the result to look.  Don't post them as an image, copy/paste them into the code editor as a table, highlight and `ctl-k` or use the `{}` button just like a code block.

Comment: Sometimes it is so frustrating to see that MySQL doesn't throw error for this kind of query.

Comment: That GROUP BY is invalid, will raise an error on newer MySQL versions (unless in compatibility mode), and return an unpredictable result on older MySQL versions. The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for not providing the full context, its been a long day, but i finally figured it out.

Here's the end query:

```
SELECT P.*, MIN(( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('37.785834') ) * cos( radians( CA.lat ) ) * cos( radians( CA.lng ) - radians('-122.406417') ) + sin( radians('37.785834') ) * sin( radians( CA.lat ) ) ) )) AS distance FROM adp2_posts as P JOIN adp2_offer_details C ON C.merchant_id = P.ID JOIN adp2_addresses CA ON CA.address_id = C.address_id WHERE P.post_type = 'merchant' AND P.post_status = 'publish' AND CA.mm = "dallasftworth" AND C.cats RLIKE CONCAT("[[:<:]]", REPLACE(199, ",", "[[:>:]]|[[:<:]]"), "[[:>:]]") GROUP BY P.ID HAVING (distance < 999999999999999999 AND P.coupon_count > 0) ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 0 , 20
```

The problem was that, `CA.address_id` where different and `GROUP BY` took it as unique values. What i did, is just select `P.*` with smallest distance(this is exactly what my business logic asks for).